# Record Audio to file while speech recognition occurs

Tags: javascript, windows-phone-8.1, cortana

Is there any way to record the audio from the mic of Windows Phone while, the speech recognition is still on ?

When I try doing this the speech recognition prompt blocks the app and thus the recorder never even starts while the recognition is going on.

```
var speechRecognizer = new SpeechRecognizer();
function startMediaCaptureSession() {
    Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.current.localFolder.createFileAsync("audio.mp3", Windows.Storage.CreationCollisionOption.generateUniqueName).then(function (newFile) {
       oMediaCapture.startRecordToStorageFileAsync(profile,newFile).then(function (result) {                            
           speechRecognizer.recognizeAsync();
       }, errorHandler);
    }  );   
}
```

Is there any way of doing it ?